# C++ default constructor is not used at runtime, but required at compile time

Tags: c++

Here is my code. If I remove default constructor, there will be error below. But if I add a default constructor, it will have no issues compiling and running. Wondering why? I am especially confused since default constructor is not used at all in runtime, why it is required at compile time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Foo {
 public:
  //Foo();
  Foo(const std::string& name, double score);
  Foo(const Foo& other);
  Foo(Foo&& other);
  const std::string& name() const { return name_; }
  double score() const { return score_; }

 private:
  std::string name_;
  double score_;
};

/*
Foo::Foo() {
  std::cout << "In default constructor " << std::endl;
  name_ = "foo";
  score_ = 1.0;
}*/

Foo::Foo(const std::string& name, double score) : name_(name), score_(score) {
  std::cout << "In parametered constructor " << std::endl;
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) {
  std::cout << "In copy constructor " << std::endl;
  name_ = other.name();
  score_ = other.score();
}

Foo::Foo(Foo&& other)
    : name_(std::move(other.name())), score_(std::move(other.score())) {
  std::cout << "In move constructor " << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<Foo> students;
  students.emplace_back("name1", 4.0);
  students.emplace_back("name2", 5.0);
  std::cout << "resizing begin " << std::endl;
  students.resize(1);
  for (Foo student : students) {
    std::cout << "student name: " << student.name()
              << " student score: " << student.score() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Error message when there is no default constructor,

```
Error:
  required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Size = long unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'
```

Successful run output when there is default constructor,

```
In parametered constructor 
In parametered constructor 
In copy constructor 
resizing begin 
In copy constructor 
student name: name1 student score: 4
```

Comment: And you don't need all those other constructors.

Comment: Calling `resize` for some arguments might require a default constructor to grow the vector. It doesn't do static analysis to determine if you only ever shrink the vector

Comment: @NeilButterworth, thx, and could you answer directly to my specific question? :)

Comment: Thanks @M.M, what do you mean "some arguments"? Do you mean for some specific use case of `resize` or for all use cases of `resize`, we all need default constructor?

Comment: @LinMa to grow the vector via `resize` elements must be default-constructed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is your call to `resize` (specifically, `students.resize(1)`); when that line is removed, the code compiles.  The issue is that `resize` has to initialize the new elements if it wasn't large enough, thus it needs the default constructor.  If you want to shrink the size of your `students` without ensuring it's a sufficient size, you can use `erase` (Max Vollmer has a specific example).

Information on `resize` is available at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).  You're falling into the first (single argument) form.

Comment: [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) doesn't work here. From the docs: If `new_cap` is greater than the current `capacity()`, new storage is allocated, **otherwise the method does nothing.** [...] `reserve()` **cannot be used to reduce the capacity of the container** [...].

Comment: @MaxVollmer - That's what I get for looking up `resize` but going off memory for `reserve`.  Thanks for keeping me honest :).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `students.resize(1);`, which needs a default constructor, you can do `students.pop_back();`, or, if the size of your vector can vary, `students.erase(students.begin()+1, students.end());`.